# Is it possible to violate Encapsulation by Reflection in ABAP?

Tags: oop, reflection, encapsulation, abap

Is it possible to:

- Read / Modify the content of a private member variable?
- Call a private method?

..from a context where these are not in scope?

Not planning to do any architecture like this, i just want to know if it's possible.

Comment: You're starting to ask more and more "dangerous" questions... :-)

Comment: they were almost going to expel me from the church of OOP :P but srsly, i needed to find a nasty bug, and to see where the problem lies, i'd have a lot less work to do if i could just modify in debugger the contents of some private member variables, than implementing 10 interfaces. If you have some other view on debugging, please share.

Comment: You can change variables in debug mode if you have the appropriate authorization (object S_DEVELOP activity 02)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the debugger is written in ABAP and the debugger can display the contents of private members, the former is possible (if not easy - you have to do some really risky low-level stuff I'd not recommend for obvious reasons). For calling private methods, I'm not sure but I'd doubt that it's possible.

Comment: However the debugger is running in a different process and it requires debug authorizations. I think this approach is not what the OP was asking for. Actually for ANY kind of system that can run in a VM you could introspect the internals from outside.This will always break all encapsulation barriers.

Comment: The debugger isn't on the outside. A JVM debugger might be, the ABAP debugger isn't. It only accesses some kernel functions that act as a "loopback".

Comment: Actually there are two debuggers. The "old" is inside, the "new" is outside.

Answer (score 2):

ABAP is an interpreted language. So the interpreter is aware of anything anytime. Even with reflection (RTTI/RTTC) and/or dynamic calls you can not access private members out of scope.

However if you have declared friends, then the friends can access private members of course.